# check Javascript library version in iOS swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode, javascriptcore

I need to call Tronweb.js , then call trxSendTest.js. So need to check Tronwebis invoked.

Out put -

version = undefined
version is undefined

```
    do {
        let TronWebJS = try String(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "TronWeb", withExtension: "js")!, encoding: .utf8)
        let trxSendTest = try String(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "trxSendTest", withExtension: "js")!, encoding: .utf8)
        
        
        
        jsContext?.evaluateScript(TronWebJS)
        jsContext?.evaluateScript(trxSendTest)
        
        let testFunction = jsContext?.objectForKeyedSubscript("tronweb.version.api")
        print("version = \(testFunction!)")
        

        
        
        if let version = jsContext?.evaluateScript("tronweb.version.api") {
            print("version is \(version)")
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("An error occurred")
    }
```

Comment: Please describe the problem you encountered.  What was the output or did you get an error?

Comment: version = undefined
version is undefined

Comment: I need to call Tronweb.js , Tronweb.js is added to Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

`tronweb.version` is the content of `package.json` which should be in the root directory of tronweb package.  It can be found on github too, https://github.com/tronprotocol/tronweb/blob/247a1eaf6d8fbf433282e1b4efc0ad4de4c673a8/package.json

You can try `tronweb.version.version` instead of `tronweb.version.api`.